# How do I fix this undeclared identifier? (C++)

Tags: c++, declaration, identifier, vst

I'm writing a VST in C++ currently, and I ran into an issue. I've been surfing the web and StackOverflow for a while now and I'm stuck. Two files are giving me the issue, `SynthesizerTwo.h` and  `SynthesizerTwo.cpp`.

The error I get is:

```
'kNumPrograms': undeclared identifier [in SynthesizerTwo.h]
```

I have a const int called kNumPrograms that is declared like this in SynthesizerTwo.cpp:

```
#include "SynthesizerTwo.h"

#pragma warning( suppress : 4101 4129 )
#include "IPlug_include_in_plug_src.h"

#include "IControl.h"
#include "resource.h"

const int kNumPrograms = 1; //Original Declaration

enum EParams
{
    kNumParams
};
```

Then, in `SynthesizerTwo.h`, it is used in the class `SynthesizerTwo` like this:

```
#ifndef __SYNTHESIZERTWO__
#define __SYNTHESIZERTWO__

#include "Oscillator.h"
#include "MIDIReceiver.h"

#pragma warning( suppress : 4101 4129 )
#include "IPlug_include_in_plug_hdr.h"

class SynthesizerTwo : public IPlug
{

public:

  SynthesizerTwo(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo);
  ~SynthesizerTwo();
  //const int kNumPrograms = 5;
  void Reset();
  void OnParamChange(int paramIdx);
  void ProcessDoubleReplacing(double** inputs, double** outputs, int nFrames);

  // to receive MIDI messages:
  void ProcessMidiMsg(IMidiMsg* pMsg);

private:
  double mFrequency;
  void SynthesizerTwo::CreatePresets() {
      
      MakeDefaultPreset((char*)"-", kNumPrograms); //This is what gives me the error
  }
  Oscillator mOscillator;

  MIDIReceiver mMIDIReceiver;
};

#endif
```

I've tried putting the declaration into the .h file, but then I get an LNK2019 linker error. I've also tried using an `extern` before the declaration in both the `.cpp.` and the `.h`.

I've tried putting the declaration outside the class in the `.h`, in the public section, and in the private section. I've also tried moving the declaration in the `.cpp` above the `.h` `#include` but I still get errors.

Linker error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall MIDIReceiver::advance(void)" (?advance@MIDIReceiver@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall SynthesizerTwo::ProcessDoubleReplacing(double * *,double * *,int)" (?ProcessDoubleReplacing@SynthesizerTwo@@UAEXPAPAN0H@Z) SynthesizerTwo-vst2 C:\wdl-ol\IPlugExamples\SynthesizerTwo\SynthesizerTwo.obj   1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `void SynthesizerTwo::CreatePresets()` should be `void CreatePresets()`. Move the implementation of that function into the `.cpp` file (after the declaration of `kNumPrograms`).

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you casting `(char*)"-"` instead of just calling `MakeDefaultPreset("-", kNumPrograms);`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure. I'll have to take a look.

Comment: I'm casting because the MakeDefaultPreset() calls for a `char*`

Comment: In that case, it does so to be able to change the content. If it tries to change the content of your `"-"` you have undefined behavior. Your program might crash or do something really strange. Don't cast. Give it an array that it's allowed to change. Do you have a link to the documentation of `MakeDefaultPreset()`?

Comment: Alright. I'm using a framework, and so I'm hesitant to change things, but I'll try it.

Comment: If the framework expects a parameter like `char*` instead of `const char*` it means that it might change the content of what the `const char*` is pointing at. Doing so has undefined behavior. Do you have a link to the documentation for `MakeDefaultPreset`? I want to read about what it does with the first parameter.

Comment: I don't, but I can provide the GitHub page to the original repo: https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol

Comment: That'll do. I downloaded the framework. I wouldn't use that. `MakeDefaultPreset` actually does _not_ change the `name` argument. It just copies it. If you supply a `nullptr` instead, it'll use the name `Empty`. Go for that instead of casting. The method _should_ be `const char*` because, as I said, it does not change what the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: Unrelated: Since the framework you linked to has been archived and they link to the new framework, [iPlug2](https://github.com/iPlug2/iPlug2), perhaps you'd be better off starting with that instead?

Comment: So instead I should use `MakeDefaultPreset((const char*)"-", kNumPrograms);`?

Comment: No, `MakeDefaultPreset(nullptr, kNumPrograms);` - A sidenote, in the new _iPlug2_ interface, they have changed it to `const char*` so that people don't have to do a pointless cast that scares people like me :-)

Comment: Ah, okay. The reason I haven't switched to iPlug2 is because the tutorial I'm following uses the old iPlug, and iPlug2 doesn't seem to be finished yet as it says [PRE-RELEASE] on their git page.

Comment: Well, it's a tough choice. Personally I wouldn't spend time learning an old archived framework when there's a new one in the making. It seems it's only pre-release because they haven't shipped their own products with it yet. I'd go for _iPlug2_ for sure. It's actively being developed so you can hope to get support on their github page if anything strange is found.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided just to switch frameworks to iPlug2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! ... and I'm looking forward to your VST plugin the next time I fire up Cubase  (... it was some 15 years ago I did it last time though ...) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your SynthesizerTwo.cpp file looks like after the pre-processor has included the files, with most cut out:

```
class SynthesizerTwo : public IPlug
{
...
  double mFrequency;
  void SynthesizerTwo::CreatePresets() {
      
      MakeDefaultPreset((char*)"-", kNumPrograms); //This is what gives me the error
  }
...

const int kNumPrograms = 1; //Original Declaration
```

As you can see, `kNumPrograms` is used before it was declared. Declaring it afterwards doesn't help. Besides, if you include "SynthesizerTwo.h" into any other file, there would not be declaration at all.

Solution: Declare variables before their use.

> But the thing is, I've tried declaring it in the .h and in the .cpp above the .h's #include. It gave me linker errors, as stated in the OP.

If you define a namespace scope variable in a header, then you should declare it `inline`.

---

```
#define __SYNTHESIZERTWO__
```

You've defined an identifier that is reserved to the language implementation. As a consequence, the behaviour of your program is undefined (would be if it compiled in the first place). You should use another header guard.

```
(char*)"-"
```

This seems dangerous. Avoid casting away constness.

Comment: To clarify the second problem: Names with `__` in them are reserved for the compiler. So maybe one day you compile this on a compiler that defines `__SYNTHESIZERTWO__` by itself, and then your header file suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: But the thing is, I've tried declaring it in the `.h` and in the `.cpp` above the `.h`'s `#include`. It gave me linker errors, as stated in the OP.

Comment: Also, I'm using a framework, and the `__` came with it.

Comment: @OboeWanKenobi Are you saying that the framework wrote SynthesizerTwo.h?

Comment: The framework came with an example file that showed how to format things, and that was part of it.

Comment: @OboeWanKenobi Well, now you know that the example that came with the framework is broken.

Comment: @eerorika The framework was created years ago and has worked for a ton of people for years. I do realize, however, that it may have changed since it was originally made.

Comment: @OboeWanKenobi It has been broken in all standard versions of C and C++. If it was written prior to 1989 (standardisation of C), then I suppose the example can be excused (but might be about time to update 30 year old examples to modern standards). `worked for a ton of people for years.` That's the thing with undefined behaviour. Just appearing to work doesn't mean that it works. It could suddenly stop working tomorrow.

Comment: @eerorika From what I can tell, it has been maintained, and it was working for me for a while (Three days).

Comment: Well, thanks for the information. I'll have to look into the header guard, as I don't know much about them.

Comment: I'm just going to move to the new Framework. As mentioned by Ted Lyngmo, the new framework does avoid casting away the constness.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to put `extern const int kNumPrograms;` in the header before the class.

The extern will work as a forward declaration and the problem will be solved.

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
//this act like a forward decleration (in your header)
extern const int kNumPrograms;
void f()
{
    std::cout<< kNumPrograms <<std::endl;
}


//real decleration come after (in your cpp)
const int kNumPrograms = 1;

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it reproducible as I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem besides `SynthesizerTwo.h` not being able to reach kNumPrograms.